# spring form:select не получаетеся

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

jsp страничка

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>


<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<form:form method="POST" modelAttribute="selectForm" class = "form-control">
    <div class="container">
            <form:select path="${login}" name="login" class = "form-control">
                <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
                <form:options items="${usersList}" itemValue="login"/>
            </form:select>
    </div>
      <input class="btn-default btn btn1" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form:form>

</body>
</html>
```

контроллер

```
@Controller
public class WaiterController{

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;



    @RequestMapping(value = {"waiter"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String waiter (Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("selectForm", userService.findAll());
        initModelList(model);
        return "waiter";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/waiter", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String waiter(@RequestParam("login") String login, Model model){
        model.addAttribute("selectForm", userService.findByLogin(login));
        initModelList(model);
        return "waiter";
    }

    private void initModelList(Model model) {
        List<User> usersList = userService.findAll();
        List<String> usersLoginList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (User user : usersList) {
            usersLoginList.add(user.getLogin());
        }
        model.addAttribute("usersList", usersLoginList);
    }
}
```

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    public enum Role {
        ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue (strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "user_id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "lastname")
    private String lastName;

    @Column(name = "login")
    private String login;

    @Column(name = "password")
    private String passwordHash;

    @Column(name = "role")
    private Role role;

    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<TableC> tableCSet;

    public User() {
    }

    public long getID() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setID(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public String getPasswordHash() {
        return passwordHash;
    }

    public void setPasswordHash(String passwordHash) {
        this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    }

    public Role getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(Role role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public Set<TableC> getTableCSet() {
        return tableCSet;
    }

    public void setTableCSet(Set<TableC> tableCSet) {
        this.tableCSet = tableCSet;
    }
}
```

проблема в том, что form:select path="" не задается

Answer (score 0):

Смешались в кучу кони, люди...

Чтобы выбор элемента сохранялся, нужно место, где он будет сохраняться. Тег Spring'а `<form:form>` ожидает в атрибуте `modelAttribute` объект [DTO](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/DTO), а в атрибуте `path` имя полей этого DTO.

**waiter.jsp**

```
...
<form:form method="post" modelAttribute="selectForm">
    <form:select path="login">
        <form:option value="NONE" label="--- Select ---" />
        <form:options items="${userList}" itemValue="login" itemLabel="login" />
    </form:select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form:form>
...
```

**UserForm.java** (DTO)

```
public class UserForm {
    private String login;

    public UserForm() {}

    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }
}
```

**WaiterController.java**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/waiter")
public class WaiterController {
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String waiter(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("selectForm", new UserForm());
        model.addAttribute("userList", userService.findAll());

        return "waiter";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String waiter(@ModelAttribute UserForm selectForm, Model model) {
        System.out.println(selectForm.getLogin());

        model.addAttribute("selectForm", selectForm);
        model.addAttribute("userList", userService.findAll());

        return "waiter";
    }
}
```

Comment: спасибо, но можно и без DTO   model.addAttribute("selectForm", new User());

Comment: [Чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) Можно и без DTO, но тогда лучше использовать html-тег form, а не spring'овый. Можно и всё вместе, но это только приводит к дополнительным трудностям.

Comment: спасибо еще раз